# symfony2 listener not called

Tags: symfony, ldap, listener

Im trying to implement this bundle: https://github.com/BorisMorel/LdapBundle

I have every thing setup and worked except for the listener - it just wont run and profiler is showing the following:

```
Not Called Listeners

Event name  Listener
imag_ldap.security.authentication.pre_bind   LdapSecurityListener::onPreBind
kernel.exception     ExceptionListener::onKernelException
kernel.exception     ProfilerListener::onKernelException
kernel.exception     ExceptionListener::onKernelException
kernel.view  TemplateListener::onKernelView
```

This is my service.yml:

```
services:
    ldap.listener:
        class: Riviera\PlutusBundle\EventListener\LdapSecurityListener
        tags:
            - {name: kernel.event_listener, event: imag_ldap.security.authentication.pre_bind, method:onPreBind}
```

And this is my listener:

```php
<?php

namespace Riviera\PlutusBundle\EventListener;

//use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use IMAG\LdapBundle\Event\LdapUserEvent;

/**
 * Performs logic before the user is found to LDAP
 */
    class LdapSecurityListener
    {

    /**
     * Modifies the User before binding data from LDAP
     *
     * @param \IMAG\LdapBundle\Event\LdapUserEvent $event
     */
    public function onPreBind(LdapUserEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getUser();
        $config = $this->appContext->getConfig();

        throw new \Exception(sprintf('Username: %s', $user->getUsername()));
    }
}
```

I have been trying for hours and I have been debugging the bundle code and can 100% say that its connecting to LDAP and failing on the following :

```php
//IMAG\LdapBundle\Provider\LdapAuthenticationProvider.php
try {
     $this->dispatcher->dispatch(LdapEvents::PRE_BIND, $userEvent);
} catch (\Exception $expt) {
     if ($this->hideUserNotFoundExceptions) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException('Bad credentials', 0, $expt);
     }

     throw $expt;
}
```

Any Thoughts/Ideas?

**EDIT**

As Per the comment below, the listener is not called and i think that the ldap functionality is reliant on having the listener called.

if i put a `die()` statement before that `try{}catch{}` i can see it in the browser, however if i put it after the die statement never fires, which means that its throwing the bad credentials exception.

Comment: What do you mean by failing in the second code example? Is it throwing a different exception to the one you're catching? Is it successfully dispatching the event and making it through the try/catch block and the listener is not firing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the listener was being called and the exception was being thrown but some functionality in the ldap module was hiding the thrown exception by masking it as a bad credentials exception.

that was happening due to `$this->hideUserNotFoundExceptions` equaling true which as far as i can see is set to default to true in the construct (cant see anywhere else that is being called)

Anyway I removed the exceptions in the listener and I have now got passed the login screen. but it still doesn't appear to have set login credentials (no token under security) but thats a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

### The problem is here:

When the ListenerClass try to access the Config objetc fails. Try to comment this in your listener.

```
    //This throw an exception
    //$config = $this->appContext->getConfig();
    //$ldapConf = $config['ldap'];

    //if (!in_array($user->getUsername(), $ldapConf['allowed'])) {
    //       throw new \Exception(sprintf('LDAP user %s not allowed', $user->getUsername()));
    //}
```